# Admob SDK integration example after apportable porting

Tags: android, admob, apportable

I'm planning to integrate admob SDK to show ads into my ported application from Cocos2d using apportable, did someone have example how to integrate Admob using apportable?

Comment: I am not familiar with apportable. What is the output from that? Is it a standard Android project folder with a manifest resources, and java files etc..? if so you should be able to implement admob the same way as any other android app (look on their site for android examples)

Comment: There is only APK file on output, looks there is possibility to manually change manifiest.xml file for now only, by changing compile scripts.

Comment: Apportable does support the AdMob APIs, but not in the Starter edition. We'll update to make this clear in an upcoming release.

Comment: Moving to answer since it's the best current answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apportable does support the AdMob APIs, but not in the Starter edition. We'll update to make this clear in an upcoming release.